# Which of these components has C-H and COOH groups

Tags: lipids

A) Amino acids and triglycerides that have a carbon-carbon double bond

or

B) proteins and fatty acids

I think they are both true, but I should choose only one
I think that because since amino acids have COOH and C-H group, proteins do too and fatty acids have these groups too just like triglycerides with a double bond. But since I have to choose one I would choose B. Am I right?

Comment: This is a homework question and off-topic unless you show some effort to solve it yourself.

Comment: I tried to edit the question to correct the spelling and chemistry terms. Please look over the edit and make sure I didn't change your meaning. Still a homework question though, and you should add your reasoning for believing both are true.

Answer (score 3):

Answer A is wrong because triglycerides are esters not carboxylic acids so they have -COOR group, not -COOH. Amino acids and fatty acids have -COOH groups and proteins too - on C-termini and in side chains.

Comment: And some amino acids will have COOH on their side chains, adding to the number of COOH groups on the protein, but this depends on the particular protein sequence.

Comment: Yes, of course.